# Image not rendering on PDF using jsPDF?

Tags: html, pdf, jquery-plugins, png, jspdf

I have included the following files:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="libs/png_support/zlib.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="libs/png_support/png.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jspdf.plugin.addimage.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jspdf.plugin.png_support.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jspdf/jspdf.plugin.standard_fonts_metrics.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jspdf/jspdf.plugin.split_text_to_size.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jspdf/jspdf.plugin.from_html.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jspdf.js"></script>
```

And I am just testing if it could render a image through html:

```
var doc = new jsPDF();
   var elementHandler = {
     '#ignorePDF': function (element, renderer) {
       return true;
     }
   };
   var source = '<img src="/assets/common/image/BG.jpg"/>';
   doc.fromHTML(
       source,
       15,
       15,
       {
         'width': 180,'elementHandlers': elementHandler
       });

   doc.output("dataurlnewwindow");
```

It throws this error on console which says:

```
jsPDF Warning: rendering issues? provide a callback to fromHTML! (anonymous function)
```

I have used PNG format, since it was not working I also tried with JPG format, still no luck!
What am I doing wrong? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Have one more argument for fromHTML()

```
doc.fromHTML(
    source,
    15,
    15, {
        'width': 180,
        'elementHandlers': elementHandler
    },

    function(dispose) {
        // dispose: object with X, Y of the last line add to the PDF
        //          this allow the insertion of new lines after html
        // pdf.save('Test.pdf');

        if (navigator.msSaveBlob) {
            var string = doc.output('datauristring');
        } else {
            var string = doc.output('bloburi');
        }

        $('.previewIFRAME').attr('src', string);
    })
```

Comment: pdf is undefined in `var string = pdf.output('bloburi');`

Comment: I am not getting the error anymore, so it did change something, but PDF generated is blank.

Comment: @klihelp even i have the same issue as the problem statement , can u please help with how you made it work for u? Seems like from_html has limited support for css ..so is that the issue?

Comment: I finally used wkhtmltopdf instead, it is open source and solved the purpose.